# on the dependence of two random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose two random variables $U$ and $V$ are defined as follows:

$$U=Z_1-X_1$$
and
$$V=Z_2-X_2$$

$Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are i.i.d random variables follows general distribution $G_Z(z)$. Furthermore, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are also i.i.d random variables follows exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. The following conditions are also met:
$$Z_1>X_1$$
$$Z_2>X_2$$
$$X_2>X_1$$

In this case, are the two random variables $U$ and $V$ dependent?

Comment: What does "the conditions are met" mean exactly? Are you conditioning on those events?

Comment: No, we assume that those conditions exist between random variables

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and identically distributed, then the condition $X_1>X_2$ cannot be assumed to be met  *unless* you are conditioning on those events.